# OData Provider in Ruby/Java

Tags: java, ruby, odata

Are there any OData **provider** SDKs for Ruby or Java?

Comment: is there any updates on a sdk for ruby or ruby on rails?

Comment: its 2017, and I still dont know of any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are none, unfortunately.

There are only clients. I've used [ruby_odata](http://github.com/visoft/ruby_odata) successfully. It works well against a simple model and provides mappings for all the basic query options, although you do need to know the operators (like eq, substringof, etc).

I did run into a more complex model and needed to tweak the code a bit. It's easy to pick up on: http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2010/07/11/odata-and-ruby.aspx

Comment: Looks lik ruby_odata is a **consumer** SDK, not a **provider** one.

Comment: This is not the correct answer, since ruby_odata is indeed a consumer (client) library, not a provider (server) library.

Comment: Well, it is correct, because there are none, at least not any practical ones that you can use and work with.

Answer (score 2):

There are providers for Ruby and Java here:
 <strike>http://www.odata.org/developers/odata-sdk</strike>

**Edit**: Previous link is broken, as mentioned below the listing is here http://www.odata.org/libraries/

Comment: That link is broken. Anyway there are no Ruby providers (as of Mar 2013) on odata.org, although Java is listed. I think the correct link is now http://www.odata.org/libraries/

Answer (score 1):

there is a project called [odata4j](http://code.google.com/p/odata4j/) on googlecode that can be used to implement producers and consumers. But i haven't tried it yet

Answer (score 1):

Apache Olingo http://olingo.apache.org/ provides an OData Java Library that implements the Open Data Protocol 2.0, support for 4.0 is in Beta.

Answer (score 0):

I published [Safrano](https://gitlab.com/dm0da/safrano) a few days ago. It's a small ruby based OData provider framework. It's far from complete and a bit experimental, but it may have some use case nevertheless